# Is there any way to relate OpenEdx to odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10, openedx

I'm working on an e learning platform using ODOO V10, and since OpenEdx uses python mainly, i wonder ifthere a connector between OpenEdx and Odoo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currently there are no OpenEdx and Odoo connector available.